# android:layout_height="match_parent" in list item gets ignored on API<11

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a simple ListView showing some content. There is real content view `@+id/conetnt` and a view `@+id/service_disabled` just to show some fancy background in case the item is disabled.
The background of the disabled view should be painted on top of the content. That's the reason for not using a background state selector for the content view.

The height of the content view differs from item to item. I basically want the disabled view height to be the same as the height of the content view.

But no matter what I try, on API<11, the disabled view height `match_parent` gets ignored.
The disabled view will have only little height.
On API>=11 everything is fine.

My list item layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/content"
                  android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="match_parent"
                  android:gravity="center_vertical"
                  android:orientation="horizontal"
                  android:padding="@dimen/service_item_padding">

        <!-- views... -->
    </LinearLayout>

    <View android:id="@+id/service_disabled"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:background="@drawable/bg_disabled_service_repeat"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

Any ideas how to fix this on API<11?

Btw: minSdk=8, targetSdk=18

It's working fine on my N4 and tf101 running both android-17.
It's broken on my HTC G2 running android-10.

Comment: Did you replace all "match_parent" with "fill_parent" and tried that?

Comment: Yes, I tried that without success.

Answer (score 0):

Think of it: what would the parent of a `ListView` item be, and what would be its height? Making a list view item equal to its parent height would make the whole list view useless.

You probably want the list row layout to have a height of `wrap_content`.

Comment: true. that's why i wrote: i want the both inner views have the same size.

Answer (score -1):

Are you compiling specifically for and older API version? Which API versions have you tested?

It can be as simple as incorrect naming. MATCH_PARENT is the name used on API 8 and higher, but if you are working on API 7 or earlier (Android 2.1 Eclair or older) you should use the constant FILL_PARENT instead.

Comment: that's not the problem. i just added it to the question: minSdk=9, targetSdk=18

Comment: And `match_parent` and `fill_parent` are the same thing, resolving to `-1` in compiled code. It's just that you cannot use `match_parent` on older SDKs where it isn't defined and `fill_parent` will give you deprecation warning on newer SDKs.

Comment: @laalto: I was not referring to compiled code, I was talking about compile time. But you are right that in compiled code it is translated to the same value.

Comment: @laalto: the question was updated now to clarify that, but when I replied, it was not obvious whether this was related to compile problems or not. Please try to help answer the question rather than trying to start unrelated debates.